# Redundancy Hungerford: Ex. 4.1.13 & 4.1.15, zero divisors and units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

Two standard exercises in Hungerford, 3rd ed.

Ex 4.1.13
Let R be a commutative ring. If $a_n \neq 0$ and $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_n x^n$ is a zero divisor in $R[x]$, prove that $a_n$ is a zero divisor in $R$.

Ex 4.1.15 (a)
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $a \in R$. If $a^3=0$, show that $1+ax$ is a unit in $R[x]$.

Ex 4.1.15 (b)
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $a \in R$. If $a^4=0$, show that $1+ax$ is a unit in $R[x]$.

Why does Hungerford insist on $R$ being commutative in the three cases above? According to his definitions:

An element $a$ in a ring $R$ with identity is called a unit if there is $u \in R$ such that $au=1=ua$, and

An element a in a ring $R$ is a zero divisor provided that $a \neq 0$ and there is $c \neq 0$ such that $ac=0$ or $ca=0$.

In exercise 4.1.13, there is $g(x) \in R[x]$ such that $f(x)g(x)=0$ or $g(x)f(x)=0$, and following multiplication we have $a_n b_m =0$ or $b_m a_n = 0$ some $0 \neq b_m \in R$.

In exercise 4.1.15 (a), $g(x)=1-ax+a^2x^2$ is an inverse$

In exercise 4.1.15 (b), $g(x)=1-ax+a^2x^2-a^3x^3$ is an inverse.

Have I made a calculation error, misread the definitions or does Hungerford impose something stronger to spare the reader some time in multiplying twice?

Comment: Does Hungerford define $R[x]$ for non-commutative $R$? If not, requiring commutativity is necessary to not invoke undefined entities.

Comment: Assuming that the variable $x$ commutes with the base ring $R$, it seems to me that you can indeed generalize these statements to the case of a non-commutative ring as you justified.

Comment: Given a ring $R$ (for which there are no additional assumptions), Hungerford shows (Theorem 4.1) that there is a ring $T$ with an element $x$ that contains $R[x] $ as a subring in which $xa=ax$ for all $a \in R$. And as Hungerford remarks, $T$ cannot be assumed to be commutative,and so the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is not necessarily commutative.

Comment: The restriction to commutativity is often done on purpose because of the concepts lateron requiring commutativity. Similarly non-associative rings like Lie rings are soon discarded.

Comment: That is just confusing without a justification like the one you gave

Comment: Careful: my copy of Hungerford defines a "zero divisor" to be an element that is **both** a left and a right zero divisor; your definition would be that of an element which is **either** a left or a right zero divisor.

Comment: Hungerford 3rd ed. p 64:

An element $a$ in a ring $R$ is a zero divisor provided that:

(1) $a \neq 0$ 
(2) There exists a nonzero element $c$ in R such that $ac=0$ or $ca=0$.

Wiki sourcing Charles Lanski (2005) seems to agree with the definition I just gave.